# Can't access backup on LUKS external HDD

Tags: virtualbox, encryption, external-hdd, luks, grsync

I encrypted a 1TB external hard drive with LUKS when formatting using Disks and used it for backups with Grsync. I had to wipe my hard drive, and now I want to restore all my files from the external disk, but I don't know how. It shows in Disks and says it's mounted but that doesn't make sense as I didn't input a password (and the pw can't have been be stored by the OS as it's a clean install), and it doesn't show in Files so I can't open it. I installed Grsync but there doesn't seem to be any way to select that disk to restore from. Other hard disks work fine. I have tried accessing it in an Ubuntu guest in Virtualbox on Windows host, but it just says there's some error connecting it.
[image]

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0 160.5M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1377
loop1         7:1    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop2         7:2    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1434
loop3         7:3    0 155.6M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1232
loop4         7:4    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop5         7:5    0 248.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop6         7:6    0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop7         7:7    0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/575
loop8         7:8    0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/582
loop9         7:9    0  43.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15177
loop10        7:10   0  44.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15534
loop11        7:11   0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/10
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0   513M  0 part 
└─sda3        8:3    0   931G  0 part /
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 953.3G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   499M  0 part
```

Comment: @Quasímodo - added lsblk.

Comment: "sudo: cryptsetup: command not found"

Comment: Yeah, looks like when I reinstalled (in order to access the backup) I accidentally installed it on the backup disk. Odd because when installing I'm sure I chose the option to delete the previous installation of Ubuntu and install in the same partition. Maybe because it was ext4 it thought it was an installation disk or something? Not sure what happened. Serves me right for doing tech stuff while watching football I suppose.

Comment: @Quasímodo - Now when I reboot without the external hard disk attached I just get some GRUB command line thing - it won't boot into Windows unless I keep the hard drive attached and select it from the menu. How do I remove the Linux stuff?